# Image slide automatically during some period of time

Tags: android, image, sliding

I have some problem with my application. I want to make my background image slide automatically without pressing any button but using time interval.
I follow some instruction from some articles but they just slide the background image using button. Does someone can help me to edit the code so the image will be slide automatically during some period of time? Thanks

Here is my code.

Java code:

```
int image[] = {R.drawable.backgroundtwo, R.drawable.backgroundthree, R.drawable.backgroundfour};

ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;
Button button;
Animation slide_in_left, slide_out_right;
int curIndex;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

    imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    slide_in_left = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    slide_out_right = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(slide_in_left);
    imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(slide_out_right);

    imageSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
        @Override
        public View makeView() {

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(Homepage.this);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            );

            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
            return imageView;
        }
    });

    curIndex = 0;
    imageSwitcher.setImageResource(image[curIndex]);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(curIndex == image.length - 1){
                curIndex = 0;
                imageSwitcher.setImageResource(image[curIndex]);
            } else {
                imageSwitcher.setImageResource(image[++curIndex]);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create anim folder under res folder
 And create one imgae_animation.xml file under anim folder
 write on imgae_animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false" >

<item
android:drawable="@drawable/img1"
android:duration="120"/>
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/img2"
android:duration="120"/>
<item
android:drawable="@drawable/img3"
android:duration="120"/>
<item
</animation-list>
```

and then add this anim under .xml to imageview

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_home_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
   android:src="@anim/imgae_animation"
   />
```

Comment: sorry but I just open and see it now, thanks for give me an inspiration about solving the problem. I appreciate it very much.